# Gradle Daemon started infinite loop

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When i Sync Project with Gradle Files, Run app or Build in Android Studio,
In Build Output, it show

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in - s --- ms
```

[image]

After it, no space remains in the memory and I have to kill Android Studio from Task Manager

[image]

I search a lot about this, nothing worked till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem for me was that my computer had enabled hotspot mode, so I disconnected it and worked for me.

The solution was given from  **korokinopio**  in the following link https://askandroidquestions.com/2020/11/06/gradle-daemon-started-infinite-loop/

Answer (score 0):

I recently through this problem and I search lots of about it but there is no perfect solution.

finally today I just solve this,

Just connect you AS(Android Studio) with internet connectivity and problem solved automatically.

Good day